# Handling Nginx location aliases when using a standalone PHP-FPM server

Tags: nginx, docker, php-fpm

I host various Laravel applications that use various versions of PHP, and decided to improve the current single bloated container Docker setup by having multiple PHP-FPM containers, one for each PHP version.

I tested the setup by having a PHP file at `/var/www/html/index.php` mounted to all containers and it works as expected.

However, since Laravel apps are served from a `public` subdirectory, this causes issue when the PHP container tries to find the file.

This is the Nginx config:

```
location /appname/ {
        alias /var/www/html/appname/public;
        index index.php;

        # Use PHP 7
                location ~ \.php$ {
                        fastcgi_pass php74:9007;
                        fastcgi_index index.php;
                        include fastcgi_params;
                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                }
    }
```

So a request to `/appname/index.php` actually gets served from `/var/www/html/appname/public`, but the PHP containers don't know this and can't find the file.

I tried replacing `$document_root` with `/var/www/html/appname/public` or `/appname/public` but neither worked.

This is the error PHP-FPM is throwing:

`FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream`

How do I go about letting PHP know the path to properly serve the app?

Feel free to recommend a better container setup to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the `location` and `alias` values should have a trailing `/` for [correct operation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias).

When using an `alias` directive, use:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
```

Comment: Solved. Thank you!